# How hot would the sun have to be to work without quantum tunnelling

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, sun, quantum-tunneling

I know that the Nuclear fusion in the sun would not work without quantum tunnelling, as the nuclei wouldn’t ever have enough energy to overcome the potential barrier.
So how hot would the sun have to be for fusion in the Sun to work without quantum tunnelling?

Comment: I would like to point out that you've asked [20 questions this month alone](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A263465+is%3Aq+created%3A2023-07..2023-07), many of which are answered and most of those answers have little to no feedback from you (i.e., comments, [accepts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), etc) on the answers the community has provided. You may want to consider appreciating the work users have put into your questions.

Answer (score 2):

From the Wikipedia article on [Nuclear fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fusion#Thermonuclear_fusion),

> In a deuterium–tritium fusion reaction, for example, the energy necessary to overcome the Coulomb barrier is 0.1 MeV. Converting between energy and temperature shows that the 0.1 MeV barrier would be overcome at a temperature in excess of 1.2 billion kelvin.

The conversion factor between the energy and temperature is, of course, the [Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant), $k_B\sim8.617\times10^{-5}$ eV/K.

As noted in the comments, the DT fusion reaction isn't the dominant process in the sun. If we used the [p-p chain instead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain), the Coulomb barrier is,
$$U_{pp}=\frac{e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\,\frac{Z_1Z_2}{R_1+R_2}\simeq0.5\,\text{MeV}$$
where $Z_i$ are the atomic number and $R_i$ the radius of the particle.
Then along with the same conversion factor,
$$T_{pp}=\frac{U_{pp}}{k_B}\simeq5\times10^{9}\text{ K}.$$
For any combination of pairs of products, this [HyperPhysics tool](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/NucEne/coubar.html) (the second box in the link contains the tool) can be used to find the requisite (Maxwellian) temperature needed to surpass the barrier (i.e., the classical value obtained when ignoring [quantum tunneling](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136738/25301) that allows for lower temperatures).

Comment: Kyle Kanos, that's pretty damned hot!

Comment: Agreed; it most certainly would be shorts weather at a billion plus kelvin.

Comment: That’s not quite what I’m asking

Comment: @blademan9999 the question you wrote is, "how hot would the sun have to be for fusion in the Sun to work without quantum tunnelling" to which the answer is 1.2 billion kelvin. If you meant to ask a different question, you need to amend your question by [editing the post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/772307/edit) to include more details of what you are asking.

Comment: The sun doesn't fuse Deuterium and Tritium for one thing. And the temperature follows a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell-Boltzmann_distribution

Comment: @blademan9999 I updated my answer to address the slightly different multiplicative factor; the result of billions of kelvin hasn't changed any, but a more precise answer is provided.

Comment: There's still the fact that were will always be atoms that are significantly hotter then the average. I don't know how much of an effect that will have though.

Comment: Okay, well you can work it out, right? You know what the Maxwellian distribution's functional form is (in terms of energy & temperature) and you have a lower-bound on the energy required. Start plugging in numbers until you have a comfortable idea. Almost surely, it's not going to be far off from the billions of kelvin this answer (and all other sources I've ever seen) provides.